# How can I cast a String to a SoapObject in ksoap2?

Tags: android, string, soap, casting, ksoap2

In my Android app I use ksoap2 for communication with a server. I download a certain complex sports information structure via soap request and parse it later in my program.

What I want to do is somehow "save" this complex structure so that I can parse it again later when all the information in that structure is final and doesn't change anymore so that I can display it without calling the web service again.

I got that far that I can turn the whole structure into a string with the toString() method from the SoapObject class so that I can save it in the app's Shared preferences.

BUT: To parse the the string with my parser that I use when I download the data directly from the web server I need it as a SoapObject. I tried something like this:

```
SoapObject soapObj = (SoapObject) dataAsStringFromSharedPrefs;
```

But I cannot cast a string to a SoapObject that way.

Comment: did you resolve your problem?

Comment: @NaveedAli I found another way for my use case. Instead of parsing/constructing a string to a soap object I parse the result to a data model, serialize it and save it to shared preferences. When I load it later, I deserialize it back to my data model.

Comment: @NaveedAli I just found a way to create a SoapObject from a string and posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This here seems to work:

```
public SoapObject createSoapObjectFromSoapObjectString(String soapObjectString)
{
// Create a SoapSerializationEnvelope with some config
SoapSerializationEnvelope env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
env.dotNet = true;

// Set your string as output
env.setOutputSoapObject(soapObjectString);

// Get response
SoapObject so = (SoapObject) env.getResponse();

return so;
}
```

Comment: I had the same requirement, I tried the above solution. but it did not work. 
It throws exception at line `SoapObject so = (SoapObject) env.getResponse();`. I think some code are missing.

Comment: yes bashahul ji. the above code is not working for me also. can kaolick help on this.. first am receiving encrypted string soap object to decrypt the response, after decrypt, am receiving response, it consider as string format xml response.need to convert again soap object to process the response

Comment: I'm not using ksoap2 any longer because I switched to REST in my app. Sorry, I won't be able to help here.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this should work fine for converting a soap XML string to a SoapObject

```
public SoapObject string2SoapObject(byte[] bytes)
{
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER12);
    SoapObject soap=null;
    try {
        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream=new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        XmlPullParser p= Xml.newPullParser();
        p.setInput(inputStream, "UTF8");
        envelope.parse(p);
        soap=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return soap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say, someObject is an object with the members CategoryId, Name, Description. If you are getting these object members in the response, you can save them to someObject by doing this:

```
SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

someObject.CategoryId =  Integer.parseInt(response.getProperty(0).toString());
someObject.Name =  response.getProperty(1).toString();
someObject.Description = response.getProperty(2).toString();
```

EDIT:

Ok I see the problem now.

To get a soapobject, only way I can think of is:

1)parse the stored string
2)store all the data fields in local variables

```
Parse stored string:

start loop
int x = something
string y = something
double z = something
end loop
```

3)create a new object using the variables

```
someObject.fieldx = x
someObject.fieldy = y
someObject.fieldz = z
```

4)create a new soapobject

```
SoapObject sp_Object = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
```

5)create a propertyinfo using the object in step 3

```
PropertyInfo prop = new PropertyInfo();
prop.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
prop.setType(someObject.getClass());
prop.setValue(someObject);
```

6)add the propertyinfo to the soapobject in step 4

```
sp_Object.addProperty(prop);
```

Then you can use the soapobject sp_Object for your parser.

Comment: Thank you, but saving parts from the response or even the complete response (f.e. as a string) is not the problem. The problem is recreating the SoapObject from the saved parts. How can I achieve THAT?

Comment: IF you need a soapobject for your parser then why convert the response to string using tostring? the response is a soapObject. try parsing it.
    SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

Comment: If I'm not mistaken I cannot save a SoapObject to the SharedPreferences for later use. That's why I convert it via toString() so that I can save it in the SharedPreferences.

Comment: I couldn't test whether you're answer is correct or not because meanwhile I changed to store the data via SQLiteDatabase. But anyway, thank you for your effort.