# How to convert string object in SoapObject

Tags: android

I have a local string which is as below:

```
String parseStr = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>"
        + "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\""
        + " xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">"
        + "<soap:Body>"
        + "<authenticateUser xmlns=\"http://playinktennismasters.com/\">"
        + "<user>Android</user>" + "</authenticateUser>" + "</soap:Body>"
        + "</soap:Envelope>";
```

I want to convert it in SoapObject and then want to parse it.

If anybody has idea how to do it, please reply.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you  may find your answer [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401715/ksoap2-how-can-i-cast-a-string-to-a-soapobject

Answer (score 1):

This here seems to work:

```
public SoapObject createSoapObjectFromSoapObjectString(String soapObjectString)
{
// Create a SoapSerializationEnvelope with some config
SoapSerializationEnvelope env = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
env.dotNet = true;

// Set your string as output
env.setOutputSoapObject(soapObjectString);

// Get response
SoapObject so = (SoapObject) env.getResponse();

return so;
}
```

Comment: not working  - all I gat is null (envelope bodyIn is null, but bodyOut isn'y)