# Android: Construct SoapObject from string

Tags: android

In one of my Android project, I have used ksoap2 library for consuming soap web service. I have a requirement to preload some data that can be used to display while the user is offline. For that i used to store the response from soap web service to the SQLite database as string. I need to find a way to reconstruct the SoapObject (response object) from the String stored in sqlite database.

I tried the approved solution mentioned in the following page, by passing previously saved response string in database to the method `createSoapObjectFromSoapObjectString()`. it throws exception as `env.getResponse()` is null.

[How can I cast a String to a SoapObject in ksoap2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13401715/ksoap2-how-can-i-cast-a-string-to-a-soapobject)

I also tried to convert the previously saved response string in database to SoapObject directly by calling following statement, but it also throws `ClassCastException` exception

`SoapObject so = (SoapObject) (Object) soapObjectString;`

The following is a sample response string that i want to construct a SoapObject from it. ()

`anyType{PatientGroupDetailDC=anyType{HasOverDueTask=No; HasUpComingTask=No; PatientReferenceNo=13; PatientName=02dvwZq8cMhx3bCH96iSMA==; NRICNumber=Gk1dfdkzJAvLJifFdBh2XA4aA==;}; PatientGroupDetailDC=anyType{HasOverDueTask=No; HasUpComingTask=No; PatientReferenceNo=TP00212011; PatientName=5OerjU0weryq/rcPR1QkxlEg==; NRICNumber=d3gFkmVkJqbGdMaO6efdVkIcQ==;};  }`

Comment: How did you get this "SoapObject" above? It looks like a debug output -- did you use `toString()` maybe? You'll need the XML response from the service instead. Alternately, you could serialize your objects...

Comment: Yes, I did use `toString()` to get the above response.

Comment: If i can construct the SoapObject from String. I can use the existing code without much modification.

Comment: Intercept the xml response and use that instead.

Comment: @323go Saved the response in Xml format to the sqlite database and was able to reconstruct the SoapObject from that Xml string. Thanks

Comment: Great news. Glad you were able to work it out.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code,

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        Object retObj = soapEnvelope.bodyIn; //OR// Object retObj = "your string response from database";
        SoapObject result = (SoapObject) retObj;
        if (result.getPropertyCount() > 0) {
            Object obj = result.getProperty(0);
        }
```

Comment: I used the above code after replacing the line 2 as below

 `Object retObj = soapObjectString; // string response from database`

On the below line, it throws class cast exception (from String to SoapObject)

`SoapObject result = (SoapObject) retObj;`